# Is there a way i can iterate over keys of a node in neo4j . Or get all the values of a node with out knowing the names of properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Following cypher query is what i am aiming for .
Match(p:Location) with  keys(p) as props foreach (prop in props| collect (p.prop) as values) return values

Comment: no it is not possible (yet), in upcoming version you will have the values function. currently you have already the keys function.

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of neo4j (since 2.2.0) now have the [KEYS() function](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/query-functions-collection.html#functions-keys), which:

> Returns a collection of string representations for the property names
>   of a node, relationship, or map.